# AJAX based application memory leak?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-applications, memory-leaks

I'm making a mobile app using Phone Gap (HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery). The application is a mobile interface to a larger website, and it uses AJAX to load web pages and display them.

My application loads pages as follows:

The HTML in question looks like this:

```
<div class="content">


</div>
```

And my snippet of java code that displays the content:

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML  = "";
            var obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = obj["data"];
        }
```

Basically, the response contains JSON data with HTML to be displayed in the `<div>` element previously mentioned by setting it's innerHTML.

However after loading a few pages, the app crashed on my Android device. Since it seemed to slowly get less responsive between pages (AJAX pages), I figured it was some sort of memory leak. I examined the web application in chrome, took memory profiles and found that the memory footprint was increasing between pages. I'm not an expert on the Chrome Developer Tools, but something that caught my eye were these "Detached DOM Tree" that appeared after loading the second page which indicates that the first page's DOM elements weren't freed from memory when the new AJAX page was loaded.

What would cause these DOM elements to not be freed properly? Is `innerHTML  = "";` not the proper way to clear all of DOM elements from another element?

I would prefer to keep my application pure AJAX, but if I have to physically switch pages for it to clear all the memory properly, then I guess I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if something still references objects, like DOM objects, the GC won't collect them. This goes for elements, even if they are removed from the DOM. Check your code for these.

Also:

- Shouldn't you be caching `document.getElementById("content")`? Calling them over and over will not change it's value. Store it in a variable instead.
- And `innerHTML` should replace *all* the element's contents. No need to clear it before putting stuff.
- If this is debugging the return, shouldn't you be logging it into `console` or something?

Like this:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
...
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  content.innerHTML = obj["data"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization suggestion. I've found what is referencing the DOM objects that prevents them from being garbage collected. I'm using jquery's .on("click" ...) to attach events. When I remove these the memory leak seems to be significantly less, however using jquery's off("click") to dettach the event doesn't seem to do anything as the memory leak still occurs when I use .off("click") on the elements. But maybe I should open another question for this issue.

Comment: @Brad maybe it's not the `on` but how you are using it.

Comment: After doing some research, I found that using jquery html() instead of innerHTML to set the contents of the <div> frees the events attached and then the DOM elements are properly freed.